# Getting the ID of the form when clicked sumbit button

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have set up a multiple form in a page with different IDs. I wanted to take ID of the form when one of the is submitted by submit btn. Here's what i got so far

```
<div class="form-wrap">
<form action="../administrator/apps/image_process_2D.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form_2D" class="submit_form">
    <input name="__files[]" type="file" multiple />
    <input name="__submit__" type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit_form" value="Upload"/>
</form>

<div class="form-wrap">
<form action="../administrator/apps/image_process_3D.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form_3D" class="submit_form">
    <input name="__files[]" type="file" multiple />
    <input name="__submit__" type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit_form" value="Upload"/>
</form>

<script>
    var my_form_id = '#upload_form'; //ID of an element for response output
    $(my_form_id).on( "submit", function(event) { 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action");
    //codes here//
    });
</script>
```

so i need the 'my_form_id' to take the value if the form ID when the submit button is clicked.

Any help if much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse to closest parent form element using `closest()` and get the id of element using `prop` or `attr`:

```
$('form').on( "submit", function(event) { 
     console.log($(this).closest('form').prop('id'));
});
```

Comment: can i get the ID before .on submit event occur?

Comment: You can not. unless the id is set. what you can do is set a global variable for id and then set its value in submit function.

Comment: tq, this works to get the ID of the form..tq very much!

Comment: @hafizyBaharudin: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.parent()](https://www.google.com.ph/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=1DlbWPa9JK3f8AfY5LuoDg&gws_rd=ssl#q=parent()+jquery)

> Description: Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$(my_form_id).on( "submit", function(event) { 
     console.log($(this).parent('form').attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: but my_form_id is not set yet, the flow is
button clicked > set my_form_id > trigger .on submit with my_form_id

Comment: what do you mean not yet set?

Comment: sorry..this works to get the ID of the form..tq very much